# How to delete or update a scheduled message

Tags: ews-managed-api

I am using the EWS Managed API to schedule messages for delayed delivery. I also have a requirement to update or delete messages after they have been scheduled for delivery.

A similar problem is outlined on msdn: [Cannot delete delayed delivery emails](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc748985-b9e9-41d8-b426-46f9e677cd41/e2007ewscwindows-cannot-delete-delayed-delivery-emails?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment). I tried the suggestion of instantiating the service without use of autodiscovery, but that did not help. (Though the idea behind the suggestion feels like it's on the right path.)

I can queue the email. I can retrieve the MailMessage item. I can set properties on the item. But whenever I call the Update, or Delete method, on a queued message a Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException is thrown.

I have tested updating and deleting MailMessage items that have been saved but *not* queued. Both update and delete work as long as message has not been queued.